# Schur Triangularization for real inner product space

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to compare Schur's triangularization theorem for the real and complex case. The theorem for the real case is:

"Let A:X→X be an operator acting in a real inner product space.  Suppose that all eigenvalues of A are real (meaning that A has exactly n= dim X real  eigenvalues,  counting  multiplicities).  Then  there  exists  an orthonormal basis u1,u2,...,un in X such that the matrix of A in this basis is upper triangular.

In other words, any real n×n matrix A with all real eigenvalues can be represented as $T=UTU^{*}=UTU^{T}$,  where U is an orthogonal,  and T is areal upper triangular matrices."

The theorem for complex case is identical except we do not assume existence of eigenvalues at all.

When the theorem is saying that we must have n real eigenvalues counting multiplicity, this is referring to algebraic multiplicity and not geometric multiplicity correct? If that was geometric multiplicity, then we can just diagonalize the matrix. But why do we need to assume we have n eigenvalues (counting multiplicity)? The proof for the complex case is just an induction proof where we only need one eigenvalue.

Also, compared to the complex case, is the theorem saying that the eigenvalues must already exist for us to triangularize the matrix? In the complex case, we can simply pull out a eigenvalue since at least one must exist due to the Fundamental theorem of algebra, but in the real case, there are matrix that has no real eigenvalues such as the rotation matrix. So we can triangularize any matrix in a complex space, the number of matric we can triangularize in the real case is quite restricted right?

Answer (score 1):

You just need the eigenvalues to be real, you don't need the matrix to be diagonalizable. In other words, it's counting algebraic multiplicities. I wouldn't get too hung up on the Theorem as stated, some versions just say "assume $A$ is a real matrix with real eigenvalues".

As you noted, there are real matrices without any real eigenvalues. But once you have a real eigenvalue, you have geometric multiplicity at least one, so you can always produce at least one eigenvector, which suffices to make the induction work.

Comment: chrome-extension://oemmndcbldboiebfnladdacbdfmadadm/https://www.math.uh.edu/~wagner/2331/Schurs_theorem.pdf  I am reading the proof by Gilbert Strang right now. The wording of the theorem is bad because it just says "Let A be a square matrix with real eigenvalues.." But I think the assumption is actually necessary. Having just one eigenvalue is not enough because unlike the complex case, you cannot guarantee by induction that the lower right block matrix has any eigenvalue at all.

Comment: The lower right block matrix must have at least one eigenvalue in the complex plane. However, it cannot be complex, because its eigenvalues are a subset of the eigenvalues of $A$. Hence it must be real, and the induction proceeds.